# Can a macro in rust use a type name as function suffix?

Tags: rust, macros

Is there a way to generate functions that contain a type's name in rust, i.e., something like this:

```rust
macro_rules! use_impl {
    ($type:ty) => {
        fn use_$type(value: $type) {
            // ...
        } 
    }
}

use_impl!(u8);
use_impl!(i8);
```

Ideally, this would generate the functions

```rust
fn use_u8(value: u8) {
  // ...
}
fn use_i8(value: i8) {
  // ...
}
```

But the compiler gives errors like this:

```
error: missing parameters for function definition
 --> src/lib.rs:3:16
  |
3 |         fn use_$type(value: $type) {
  |                ^ help: add a parameter list
...
9 | use_impl!(u8);
  | ------------- in this macro invocation
```

[Playgrounds link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6360167dcfc79043345cba26509c51a6)

Comment: I suspect you have to write procedural macros for this. IIRC there's no way to assemble identifiers with macro_rules.